# Compare Two Images And Detect Feature Of Those

Tags: python, opencv

i am researching in image proccessing with OpenCV and python for 'reverse image search' and 
my question is that how can i find out the various objects in image.
i use cv2.calchist for finding the feature of image and training  but it has not good result in finding the object ,the result  that it give me is more  according to the color  and not the shape and features

my code for extract feature is:

```
image=cv2.imread(args["query"])
hsvimg = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(hsvimg, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
edged = cv2.Canny(hsvimg, 50, 100)
edged = cv2.dilate(edged, None, iterations=1)
edged = cv2.erode(edged, None, iterations=1)
cnts = cv2.findContours(edged.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
                    cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if imutils.is_cv2() else cnts[1]

features = []

(cnts, _) = contours.sort_contours(cnts)

maxArea = -1
#detect bigest ellipse
for c in cnts:
    if len(c) < 5:
        continue

    (ex, ey), (MA, ma), angle = cv2.fitEllipse(c)

    if angle == 0:
        continue

    ellipseArea = math.pi * MA * ma / 4

    if ellipseArea > maxArea:
        maxArea = ellipseArea


for c in cnts:
    if len(c) < 5:
        continue
    (ex, ey), (MA, ma), angle = cv2.fitEllipse(c)
    if angle == 0:
        continue

    ellipseArea = math.pi * MA * ma / 4
    if ellipseArea != maxArea:
        continue

    ellipse = cv2.fitEllipse(c)


    mask = np.zeros(image.shape[:2], dtype="uint8")
    cv2.ellipse(mask, ellipse, 255, -1)

    hist = cv2.calcHist([image], [0, 1, 2], mask, self.bins, [0, 180, 0, 256, 0, 256])
    hist = cv2.normalize(hist, hist, 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX).flatten()

    features.extend(hist)

return features
```

this code say two below imeges is same

[Image Of Sky](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AcY7N.jpg)

[Image Of Car](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91YDw.jpg)

Comment: Please provide some example of your code